# Tabs and Nerdtree

Tags: vim, vi, nerdtree

I'm looking for a way to either:

- Persist NerdTree across all open Tabs
  OR
- Open Files in new tabs while maintaining the focus on NERDTree

I've tried a number of approaches. For example using

```
autocmd TabEnter * NERDTreeToggle
```

That gets quite messy. The tab opens with NERDTree on the right side. And If I focus on another tab and go back to the new tab it opens a third split with the NERDTree correctly on the right side.

I'm also trying to simply use <kbd>T</kbd> when opening a file. The focus doesn't change to new file alright but it NERDTree disappears and I'm left in a 'No Name' tab.

Anyone have a neat solution here?

UPDATE:

reset NERDTree to HEAD - <kbd>T</kbd> on open started to work

I'd still really like a solution to keep NERDTree open by default on left of all tabs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen [this project](https://github.com/jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs) a while ago. I've never tried it because I'm not interested in that feature, maybe others did?

But you should stop trying to use Vim as if it was Gedit or TextMate or whatever other editor you are used to. Tabs in Vim don't work at all like tabs in other editors: you can't think of them as 1:1 "proxies" for specific files because they can contain any number of "files" and their names are succeptible to change in many ways.

Instead, learn about "buffers" and "windows".

Comment: Reading a bit more on this subject. I think you are right. I was too much in the textmate frame of mind.

Comment: Also for coding combining NerdTree on left and Taglist with all files open you have a easy access to all files/functions.

Comment: That's definetely very subjective. For me, having a list of the files in my project open all the time is useless: such a list may be useful *when* I actually need to open another file but that's not something I do often enough to have a file explorer open all day long. The same goes for TagBar (and TagList). When I was using TextMate I was a heavy <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> user for file navigation and I always closed the project drawer, now that I'm using Vim, I don't use NERDTree and I love [CtrlP](http://kien.github.com/ctrlp.vim/).

Comment: What about having a small monitor (as compared to the number of files to edit)? Sometimes you just need to use tabs because there's not enough space for splitting windows in one tab only. This is just to say that the feature the OP reqeusted could be useful in some circumstances.